# How to use Activator.CreateInstance() to call an override C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, overriding, activator

I am looking to find the proper way to call a overridden function of an inherited class using the `Activator.CreateInstance()` function. I am doing this so that I can call a specific function of a derived class based on a string object, such that the string determines which derived class object will be created and have its function called. Something like this but I do not know how to do it properly or if there is a better way than using Activator.

```
public class Test
{
    public virtual void DefaultCalibration()
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
}

public class EasyTest : Test
{
    public override void DefaultCalibration()
    {
        //Do one thing
    }
}

public class HardTest : Test
{
    public override void DefaultCalibration()
    {
        //Do another thing
    }
}

public class Tester
{
    public void main()
    {
        string testName = ""; 

        // ...
        // ... Do some stuff to get a string of the name of the class, ie testName = "HardTest";
        // ...

        Type type = Type.GetType(testName);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        ((Test)instance).DefaultCalibration(); //this line doesn't call the derived function
    }
}
```

I want it so that the derived class' override function is called instead of the base class function.

The intent being that if my string is "HardTest", then it would essentially look like

`((HardTest)instance).DefaultCalibration();`

but if it was "EasyTest" then it would look like

`((EasyTest)instance).DefaultCalibration();`

Comment: I don't think there is another way then using Activator, when you want to determine type on runtime.

Comment: No kind of cast is going to let you call the wrong virtual method.  Even if you hack Reflection.Emit then the verifier will still stop you from executing fundamentally memory-unsafe code.  You must create an object of the correct type, rock hard.

Comment: Okay thanks. That is probably the answer I was expecting but I wanted to be sure, or see if there was an alternative way to do it. I guess the best way to implement it is by using a switch statement on the string and creating each type and calling DefaultCalibration() on the actual object. Agree?